# how to send a email automatically at particular time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to send a email automatically at particular time like a reminder in asp.net with c# sql

**my code:**

```
try {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT Name,Date  FROM Reminder (DAY, Date) = @DAY AND DATEPART(MONTH, Date)= @Month ";
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["reminderconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", DateTime.Today.Day);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", DateTime.Today.Day);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
        string name = row["Name"].ToString();
        string email = row["Email"].ToString();
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = "Meeting";
        msg.Body = string.Format("Meeting for a week", name);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
        credentials.UserName = "xxxxxxxx";
        credentials.Password = "xxxxxxxx";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = credentials;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(msg);

    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.Write("Error message");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: add error / describe your problem

Comment: Write a console application, use Task Scheduler to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quartz.Net to achieve your result. You have to install it as a service on server.

[Tutorial here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) and some Hello world programs [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-writing-your-first-hello-world-job.aspx)

Basically you write your job to schedule, a trigger for the job and schedule it for mailing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hangfire to schedule background recurring processes in asp.net

check http://hangfire.io/